# What wakes the Kraken?

Tags: sleepy-kraken

I thought if I destroyed all the ships quickly the Kraken would stay sleeping but it seems like some things wake him up, like bells and maybe sheep and maybe TNT explosions.

What causes the Kraken to be less sleepy and eventually wake up?